iOS LiveActivity update not possible
Since a couple of days (not sure if it has something to do with the latest iOS updates - iOS 17.4) my live activities are not working any more.
I create them like so:
let attributes = MyWidgetAttributes()
let contentState: ActivityContent<MyWidgetAttributes.ContentState> = .init(state: .init(somePropertiesInHere:<xxx>),
                                                                           staleDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(60 * 60)) // 1h
                        
let widgetActivity = try Activity.request(attributes: attributes,
                                          content: contentState)

and that seems to work fine. The widgetActivity property is not nil and when I query Activity<MyWidgetAttributes>.activities right afterwards I do get it back.
My problem is now, that only a couple of seconds later, the same request (in order to update my live-widget with live data) would not return anything any more and therefore can't be updated. I also don't see any widget on the home-screen.
And now an other fun-fact. When I restart my phone, it works again...
Did I miss something about that whole feature with iOS 17.4? Do I need to adopt something? Or is this an iOS bug? Does anybody else experience similar things?
